# Can JS package publishers point to relative directory of modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules

I've recently started building isomorphic packages with things like .esm and .jsx files transpiled for node.js while also consumable by bundlers like webpack.  I know that I can point consumers in the right direction by providing, main, module or browser keys in the package.json.  eg.

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "react-patterns",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/components/index.js",
  "browser": "components/index.js",
  ...
```

and this will work well when index.js exports a list of components, eg.

```
// index.js

import Image from './Image';
import Button from './Button';
export { Image, Button }

// consumer.js

import { Button } from 'react-patterns';
```

But in the effort to be lazy (or write less accounting code), would it be feasible to write something like this in my package.json?

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "react-patterns",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/components",
  "browser": "components",
  ...
```

And have the Button.js and the Image.js module right there at the top of the directory?  So a consumer could do something akin to `import merge from 'lodash/merge;` eg.

```
// consumer.js

import Button from 'react-patterns/Button';
```

Maybe a bit esoteric or even bad practice?  Regardless, I haven't seen anybody mentioning this in a tutorial or asking on a SO thread. Friday problems, amiright?